# Count results rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have results like that:[All results](http://yx.ee/kliendid/baltosport/kuva/tulemus_liige.php) And from results is [Ranking list](http://yx.ee/kliendid/baltosport/kuva/liikmeteedetabel2015.php)

query:

```
  $results = $mysqli->query(" 
  SELECT tv.*,
       (@rn := @rn + 1) as ranking
FROM (SELECT liige_v.liige_id, liige_v.Eesnimi, 
             liige_v.Perekonnanimi, punktid, SUM(punktid) AS punktidkokku
      FROM tulemus INNER JOIN
           liige_v
           ON tulemus.liige_id = liige_v.liige_id
      GROUP BY tulemus.liige_id
     ) tv CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0) vars
ORDER BY punktidkokku desc;
");
```

table:

```
print '<table class="mytable4">';
echo "<tr><th>Koht </th><th>Liikme nimi </th><th> count results</th><th>Punktid</th></tr>";
while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {

 print '<tr>';
 print '<td>' .$row["ranking"].'</td>';
   print '<td>'.$row["Eesnimi"].'  '.$row["Perekonnanimi"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["countresults"].'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["punktidkokku"].'</td>';
    
 print '</tr>';

}  

print '</table>';
```

How I get "count results" as how many results give sum of points ?
In my example first Aivar Narusson have 288 points from 4 races (count results = 4)

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  I, for one, have no idea what your example is referring to.  A SQL Fiddle can also help.  And do not use external sites for information relevant to the question.  If the sites are not available, the question makes no sense.  Try to include all relevant information in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* I understand the question.  If you want the count, just include `count(*)` in the aggregation:

```
SELECT tv.*,
       (@rn := @rn + 1) as ranking
FROM (SELECT liige_v.liige_id, liige_v.Eesnimi, 
             liige_v.Perekonnanimi, punktid,
             COUNT(*) as cnt, SUM(punktid) AS punktidkokku
      FROM tulemus INNER JOIN
           liige_v
           ON tulemus.liige_id = liige_v.liige_id
      GROUP BY tulemus.liige_id
     ) tv CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @rn := 0) vars
ORDER BY punktidkokku desc;
```